# MQRA:MC:Warning:createConnection API used w/o username, password for Application Auth|#]

Tags: jms

Does anyone know why this error occurs and how to resolve it?
It only seems to occur when we hit an exception.

> [#|2008-11-14T14:49:12.482+0800|WARNING|sun-appserver-pe8.2|javax.enterprise.system.stream.err|_ThreadID=12;|
>       MQRA:MC:Warning:createConnection API used w/o username, password for Application Auth|#]

Answer (score 0):

This seems very similar to this [too many open files problem](http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=218478)